# Uploading images from Strapi to Cloudinary not working in production mode

Tags: server, strapi, cloudinary, railway

I'm trying to upload images to my Strapi server, it works perfectly on localhost, it show the images and upload to Cloudinary. I deployed the server on Railway and everything works fine but i can't upload images or any files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyRBT.png)

I follow the Strapi provider Cloudinary documentation and work perfectly on Localhost.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the project settings are still set for the localhost project and wasn't updated to reflect the Railway server.

Try checking the documentation here: https://dev.to/yinks/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-strapi-project-on-railway-3kja , to ensure the host is defined correctly.